# Why is Zekrom easier to capture than Kyurem?

Tags: pokemon-fifth-generation

In the fifth generation of Pokémon games (Black and White and their sequels), Zekrom and Kyurem appear to have the same capture rate (3, according to Bulbapedia), but Zekrom is much easier to capture. Why is this?

This can be illustrated using [a capture calculator](https://www.dragonflycave.com/calculators/gen-v-catch-rate), if that would help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In generation 5 games, Reshiram and Zekrom have a capture rate of 45, not 3. Of course a Zekrom's 45 capture rate would make it easier to capture than Kyurem's 3 capture rate.

Comment: I am unsure why this answer was downvoted--it is the correct answer. Zekrom has a catch rate of 45 in 5th generation. The capture rate of 3 listed on Bulbapedia is true for more recent generations.